# Android LinearLayout - wrap_content + Split remaining space

Tags: android, android-layout, layout

Consider the following layout: a horizontal LinearLayout with 2 buttons with the text "Push me", and an ImageButton with a small envelope icon (for example, to send an email).

I want the ImageButton's width to be set to "wrap_content" so it's only as large as the envelope's size, and then I want the other two buttons to evenly split the remainder of the screen evenly. How can it be done?

Answer (score 1):

`layout_weight` specifies how much of the extra space in the layout to be allocated to the View.
So, for your envelope ImageButton set the `android:layout_width="wrap_content"`. And for your remaining 2 buttons set `android:layout_width="0dp"` and add  `android:layout_weight="0.5"` to both buttons.

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
<LinearLayout
  xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
  android:layout_width="match_parent"
  android:layout_height="wrap_content">

  <ImageButton
    android:id="@+id/ib"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:src="@mipmap/ic_launcher"/>

  <LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="0dp"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_weight="1"
    >

    <Button
      android:layout_width="wrap_content"
      android:layout_height="wrap_content"
      android:layout_weight="1"
      android:text="Push me"/>

    <Button
      android:layout_width="wrap_content"
      android:layout_height="wrap_content"
      android:layout_weight="1"
      android:text="Push me"/>

  </LinearLayout>
</LinearLayout>
```